# Calling recursively through the hierarchy (Java)

Tags: java, recursion, comparison

I have got stuck in some issue where I need to traverse through a hierarchy and compare some values and moment I got match need to return the result.  Here is my complete use-case

I am getting `Collection<Categories> categoryList` and A `Collection<MyCustomObject>`, 
MyCustomObject{
 // some properties
  private Category category
}

I need to compare the code of category with the code of category coming under MyCustomObject and need to send back MyCustomObject with first match.

For this comparison I need to traverse through the hierarchy of Collection i.w if the match is not found in the current category need to get Category list by calling
`categoryList.getSuperCategories()` and then go upward.

I though of recursive method call but seems like this is not working in my case as if I keep traversing the first category till the root I am not able to keep track of the second one.

I was trying something (not completed nor working correctly)

```
public ProductAllotmentData getProductAllotmnet(final Collection<CategoryModel> categoryModelList)
 {
  if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(categoryModelList))
  {
   final List<ProductAllotment> productAllotmentList = getProductAllotmentEntries();
   if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(productAllotmentList))
   {
    for (final CategoryModel model : categoryModelList)
    {
     for (final ProductAllotmentData productAllotmentData : productAllotmentList)
     {
      if (model.getCode().equals(productAllotmentData.getAllotmentCategory().getCode()))
      {
       return ProductAllotmentData;

      }
      else
      {
       return getAllotmentForCategory(model.getAllSupercategories(), productAllotmentyData);
      }
   }
    }
   }
  }

  return null;
 }
```

--

```
public ProductAllotmentData getAllotmentForCategory(final Collection<CategoryModel> categoryModelList,
       final ProductAllotmentData productAllotmentaData)
     {
      ProductAllotmentData allotmentData = null;
      for (final CategoryModel model : categoryModelList)
      {
       if (model.getCode().equals(productAllotmentData.getAllotmentCategory().getCode()))
       {
        allotmentEntryData = productAllotmentData;

       }
       else
       {
        return getAllotmentForCategory(model.getSupercategories(), productAllotmentData);
       }
      }

      return allotmentEntryData;
     }
```

other option came to my mind is to create a kind of stack and put all categories in that and den pop them one at a time compare them and send back the first match ignoring rest of the items in the stack but i m looking for much better and flexible solution.

**Problem**

I am not sure how I can traverse hierarchy of each category up to compare its code.  `getAllotmentForCategory` is where i am trying to traverse my category hierarchy.

Any help in this regard is really good

Comment: SometimesWhenYouUseReallyLongVariableNamesItDoesntImproveClarity I can't see where you are recursing. What is your question?

Comment: @PeterLawrey That one was Great !!!

Comment: `I have got struck in some issue` -- You haven't told your issue till now..

Comment: @PeterLawrey:sorry for poorly designed question as this is my first question here.I have edited my question and hope it is more clear now.

Comment: @RohitJain: i have updated my question with information where i m struck.

Comment: The method needs to call itself with the object you want to traverse to. It also need to know when to stop i.e. when it has reached the end.

Comment: @FindingNemo.. You have still not quoted, what's wrong with that code.. `What problem are you facing?`-  is important.. Not just `you are facing problem`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to traverse back to child categories when you reach the root. Instead Go directly to root and go down until you find them with recursive method.

like... (the code is not copy paste code)

```
public ProductAllotmentEntryData recursive(root, code) { 
 if(root.code == code) 
    return root;
 }else{ 
    for(root.childs){ 
        object = recursive(child, code) 
        if(object!=null) 
            return object;
    } 
 return null;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To do what I think you described ...

```
public ProductAllotmentData getAllotmentForCategory(
       final Collection<CategoryModel> categoryModelList,
       final ProductAllotmentData productAllotmentaData) {
    for (final CategoryModel model : categoryModelList) {
        if (model.getCode().equals(
                productAllotmentData.getAllotmentCategory().getCode())) {
            return productAllotmentData;
        }
    }
    for (final CategoryModel model : categoryModelList) {
        if (model.getSupercategories() != null) {
            return getAllotmentForCategory(
                    model.getSupercategories(), productAllotmentData);
        }
    }
    return null;  // or throw an exception.
}
```

Note that this assumes that the 'categories' are hierarchical; i.e. there are no cycles in 'category' graph.  It also assumes that you want to return the 'allotment' for the first 'category' that matches ... irrespective of the fact that other 'categories' could match as well.

---

(The problem is that you don't describe the problem in enough detail.  So it is not possible to figure out what 'product', 'category' and 'allotment' mean, and hence what is the *semantically* correct way to get an 'allotment'.)